# Merge table by cell content, row index

Tags: r, matrix, match, lookup

I want to read out the *column* numbers for each (unique) value in a matrix, and add that value to a new table with original cell values as rownames in a new matrix.

Here's a minimum working example (MWE):

One of many (one per person) matrices `fruit_ranking_person1`.

```
fruit_ranking_thomas <- matrix(
c(
    "NA", "Pear", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Peach", "Rasberry", "Grapefruit", "Orange", "NA", "Apple"
),
nrow = 2
)

print(fruit_ranking_thomas)
     [,1]   [,2]         [,3]       [,4]         [,5]   
[1,] "NA"   "Banana"     "Peach"    "Grapefruit" "NA"   
[2,] "Pear" "Strawberry" "Rasberry" "Orange"     "Apple"
```

This original matrix gives the ranks (from 1 to give) that one person has given to each of these fruit.

Should turn into this matrix `fruit_ranking_aggregate` (hard-entered here for illustration):

```
Fruit,      Thomas,    Lisa
Apple,       5         ...
Pear,        1
Banana,      2
Strawberry,  2
Peach,       3
Rasberry     3
Grapefruit,  4
Orange,      4
```

I also already have an **empty** matrix `fruit_ranking_aggregate`:

```
fruit_ranking_aggregate <- matrix(
  , # empty for now
  nrow = 8, # let's say there are 7 fruit
  ncol = 3, # let's say there's going to be 3 people
  dimnames = list(
    c(
        "Apple", "Banana", "Grapefruit", "Orange", "Peach", "Pear", "Rasberry", "Strawberry"
    ),
    c("Thomas", "Lisa", "Peter")
  )
)

print(fruit_ranking_aggregate)
               Thomas Lisa Peter
Apple          NA   NA    NA
Banana         NA   NA    NA
Grapefruit     NA   NA    NA
Orange         NA   NA    NA
Peach          NA   NA    NA
Pear           NA   NA    NA
Rasberry       NA   NA    NA
Strawberry     NA   NA    NA
```

Note further:

- for simplicity, I'm using the colname in `fruit_ranking_person1` as the ranking; preferred fruit are on the right.
- there are `NA`s in `fruit_ranking_person1`.
- the fruit in `fruit_ranking_person1` are unique within each `person` matrix; there are no duplicate mentions (I test that on data entry)
- the vertical dimension (different rows) in `fruit_ranking_person1` is meaningless – still, data take this form on entry (it's a [q-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_methodology), if anyone's interested)
- I know I still have to loop over (or something) over person1-n, but that's a different concern.

Ps.: I am aware that is uncommon to have people as columns, not as rows – the method (q-methodology) I am using calls for it.

Comment: While I'm at it, I also can't get the StackExchange formatting to work for the first table. Darn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that does the trick, but I have a hunch there's *got* to be a more elegant/clever way to do this...

```
for (n in rownames(fruit_ranking_aggregate)){
    fruit_ranking_aggregate[n,"Thomas"] <- which(fruit_ranking_thomas == n, arr.ind = TRUE, useNames = TRUE)[2]
}
print(fruit_ranking_aggregate)
           Thomas Lisa Peter
Apple           5   NA    NA
Banana          2   NA    NA
Grapefruit      4   NA    NA
Orange          4   NA    NA
Peach           3   NA    NA
Pear            1   NA    NA
Rasberry        3   NA    NA
Strawberry      2   NA    NA
```

Done! – but feels cumbersome. Plus I still have to wrap this in 2 more layers of for-loops (for the people, and for the treatment conditions ...)